# XLarge Layout using same mdpi icons

Tags: android

I'm trying to create layout for xlarge devices (I'm testing it on Note 10.1 (1280x800)).

I have icon for every density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) and ImageButtons that use it.

Problem is that when I set on ImageButton "android:src="@drawable/image1"" and run it on xlarge device it still uses mdpi instead of xxhdpi icons.

How to fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is `mdpi`, as should be any ~10" tablet that is WXGA800 (1280x800) resolution. Your device is not `xxhdpi`. `xlarge` does not imply `xxhdpi`, as **screen size has nothing to do with screen density**. Size and density are independent attributes.

Hence, your app should be using `mdpi` icons for this device.

Answer (score 1):

So Note 10.1 (1280x800) is **xlarge** where it 'xlarge' is about screen size, about physical size (screen inches).

And mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc. is about **density** of pixels.